# Assigning data and time to FILETIME structure in C++

Tags: c++

In windows and in C++. I have following code.

```
typedef struct _FILETIME {
    DWORD dwLowDateTime;
    DWORD dwHighDateTime;
} FILETIME, *PFILETIME, *LPFILETIME;

struct DateTime
{
    unsigned int dwLowDateTime;
    unsigned int dwHighDateTime;
};

FILETIME ftTime;
GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ftTime);

DateTime myTime;
myTime.dwHighDateTime = (unsigned int)ftTime.dwHighDateTime;
myTime.dwLowDateTime  = (unsigned int)ftTime.dwLowDateTime;
```

Now I have requirement to assign values like

```
2012-06-25 12:00:10.123
```

to "myTime" or ftTime.

How can I achive this?

Another question is how can I get number of seconds elapsed like 64-bit integer for date "2012-06-25 12:00:10.123" ? How do I convert this to __int64 so that I assign to FILETIME?

I have seen in another question post

```
__int64 t;
FILETIME ft;
ft.dwLowDateTime = (DWORD)t;
ft.dwHighDateTime = (DWORD)(t >> 32);
```

I am not supposed to use Boost in my project.

Thanks!

Comment: you want to know how to format the time?

Comment: question is how to assign "2012-06-25 12:00:10.123" to ftTime?

Comment: how can you assign a string to ftTime? or do you mean representing the value you have mentioned inside ftTime

Comment: yes, like I think I have to convert the above time into number os 100ns elapsed (in windows we have 100ns resolution) from utc time and then assign that integer to __int64? I am not getting how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assign the value  "2012-06-25 12:00:10.123" to the SystemTime structure and convert it into FileTime using the function SystemTimeToFileTime.

```
SYSTEMTIME st,st1;
st.wDay = 25;
st.wMonth = 06;
st.wYear = 2012;
st.wHour = 12;
st.wMinute = 10;
st.wSecond = 10;
st.wMilliseconds = 10;

FILETIME ft;
SystemTimeToFileTime(&st,&ft);
FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft,&st1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SystemTimeToFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Assign the datetime data to the `SYSTEMTIME` structure.

```
typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
  WORD wYear;
  WORD wMonth;
  WORD wDayOfWeek;
  WORD wDay;
  WORD wHour;
  WORD wMinute;
  WORD wSecond;
  WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME, *PSYSTEMTIME;
```

And use

```
BOOL WINAPI SystemTimeToFileTime(
  __in   const SYSTEMTIME *lpSystemTime,
  __out  LPFILETIME lpFileTime
);
```

for the conversion.

Update:
For converting from the string to date,time components, you can use `DateTime::Parse Method(String)` method.
Then assign the values to the `SYSTEMTIME` structure and then convert that to `FileTime`.

Comment: can I assign directly to SYSTEMTIME structure values? Can you please show an example? I am new to Windows programming.

Comment: @venkysmarty I see no reason why you can't. But if you think that you can assign your date/time string directly to it, that you can't do in C(++). You'll need to first parse out your string to find out the numerical values of the year, month, day, hours, etc. Only then you'll be able to assign members of `SYSTEMTIME`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways and functions that can get you there.

You can use [`DosDateTimeToFileTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert year/month/day h:m:s into `FILETIME`. You'll need to take additional care of the odd seconds and second fractions.

You also have C(++)'s [`mktime()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/mktime/) to first get time in seconds since 1970. Then you'd need to convert it to seconds since January 1st 1601 by adding 11644473600 to it, scale it to 100-nanoseconds and add the seconds fraction.

But [`SystemTimeToFileTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a better choice because it handles milliseconds as well.

It's not clear what you mean by `how can I get number of seconds elapsed like 64-bit integer for date "2012-06-25 12:00:10.123"?`

Seconds elapsed since then until now? If so, you get the current time in seconds and convert the given date/time to seconds (described above) and subtract one from the other.

Seconds elapsed since an earlier time until then? Do the same, get seconds for both date/time pairs and subtract.